# richTextEditor problem in symfony

Tags: tinymce, symfony-1.4

I have installed sfExtraPluginForm in my symfony and i want to get a rich text editor in my forms but it just shows a simple textarea.

I have  installed sfExtraPluginForm and created a form in form folder.

The code i have written is:

> $this->setWidgets(array(
>                 'title'  =>  new sfWidgetFormInput(),
>                   'description' => new sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE(array(
>               'width'  => 550,
>         'height' => 350,
>         'theme' => 'advanced',
>           ))

What more do I need to do?

Comment: Do you have installed the tinymce library? If I'm right, it isn't included in sfFormExtraPlugin plugin.

Comment: You're right : [official docu](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFormExtraPlugin)
> As no third party libraries is bundled in the plugin, you need to install and load the required dependencies like JQuery, JQuery UI, or TinyMCE by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to load tinyMCE library. 
Download it from the [offcial website](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php) and include tiny_mce.js in your page.